# Understanding a part of the proof that $\xi^{\alpha}(\mathcal F \varphi)(\xi) = (-i)^{|\alpha|} \mathcal F (D^{\alpha}\varphi)(\xi)$

Tags: fourier-analysis, proof-explanation

Let $\varphi \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb R^n)$ and $\xi \in \mathbb R^n$, $\xi_l$ its $l$th coordinate. We can use that $x^{\alpha}\varphi$,$D^{\alpha}\varphi \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb R^n)$, where $\alpha \in \mathbb N^n_0$ (the usual multiindex notation). How do I see that the following holds:

$\xi_l (\mathcal{F}\varphi)(\xi) =$$ i \over (2\pi)^{-n/2}$$\int_{\mathbb R^n}$$\partial \over \partial x_l$$(e^{-i\langle x, \xi \rangle})\varphi(x) dx$

without using that $\xi^{\alpha}(\mathcal F \varphi)(\xi) = (-i)^{|\alpha|} \mathcal F (D^{\alpha}\varphi)(\xi)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see that, write out the definition of the Fourier transform, move the $\xi_l$ inside the integral, and compare $\xi_le^{-ix\cdot\xi}$ with $\partial_{x_l}e^{-ix\cdot\xi}$.
Can you complete the puzzle with these hints?
Let me know if some step needs elaboration.

Comment: Now it's clear, since $\partial_{x_l} {- 1 \over i} e^{-ix\cdot\xi} = \xi_l e^{-ix\cdot\xi}$ and ${- 1 \over i} = i$.

Comment: I honestly thought this was supposed to be one (more) property of the FT which I overlooked.

Comment: @Pazu Oh yes, this particular identity is not a property of the FT, but just of the underlying concepts (integral, derivative, exponential). It all happens very conveniently, and that is what gives the FT that nice property. That proof is about deriving properties of the FT, not using them.